# How to display correctly several Flatlist with a map function?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an issue that I don't quite understand.

I would like to display messages contained in an array using several flatlists. Then I will have to group them by date.

The messages actually correspond to a series of questions and answers from a chat where each message is recorded in an offline database (PouchDB is used). So I would like to display in an interface the questions that the user has answered, in short, I want to view the logs.

Here is the code:

```js
const screen = Dimensions.get('screen');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logsView: {
    backgroundColor: '#dddddd',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 2,
    height: '100%',
  },
  dateContainer: {
    width: '75%',
    padding: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  dateContent: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

});

export default class ComponentPlanDetailsScreen
  extends ComeoMeAbstractScreen<PropsType, StateType> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: µte('MyPlans'),
    headerRight: (<View />),
  };


  constructor(props: PropsType) {
    super(props);
    this.IfeelMessagesBusiness = new IfeelMessagesBusiness();
    this.state = {
      currentDate: new Date(),
      markedDate: moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      messages: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Get all messages from chat history
    this.IfeelMessagesBusiness.getAllIfeelMessages().then((result: Object) => {
      this.setState({ messages: result });
    });
  };

    // Render each item of Flatlist
    renderLogItem = ({ item }: Object) => {
      console.log(`je passe renderlogitem ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
      return <LogItem message={item} />;
    }
    // Key for data in FlatList component
    keyExtractor = (item: Object, index: number): string => index.toString();

    render() {
      const test = [
        {
          stringValue: 'Did you take some drugs ?',
          isImage: false,
          isQuestion: true,
          questionNumber: 6,
          author: {
            id: 1,
            avatar: 'http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/47/1480031586-1474755093-risitas721.png',
            username: 'Dr Risitas',
          },
          loggedDateTime: '1552033946989',
        },
      ];
      const today = this.state.currentDate;
      const day = moment(today).format('x');
      return (
        <View>
          <Carousel
            animate={false}
            indicatorSize={10}
            height={screen.height * 0.7
            }
          >
            <View>
              <ScrollView
                style={styles.logsView}
              >
                <View>
                  {this.state.messages.map((ItemListByDate: Object): Array<Object> => {
                  console.log(`je passe array ${JSON.stringify([ItemListByDate])}`);

                    return (

                      <View key={ItemListByDate.loggedDateTime.toString()}>
                        <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                          { (parseInt(ItemListByDate.loggedDateTime, 10) + 172800000) <= parseInt(day.toString(), 10) ?
                            <Text style={styles.dateContent}>{moment(parseInt(ItemListByDate.loggedDateTime, 10)).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}</Text>

                          :

                            <Text style={styles.dateContent}>{moment(parseInt(ItemListByDate.loggedDateTime, 10)).fromNow()}</Text>
                         }
                        </View>
                        <View>
                          <FlatList
                            data={[ItemListByDate]}
                            renderItem={this.renderLogItem}
                            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                            ref={(ref: any) => { this.flatList = ref; }}
                            onContentSizeChange={(): any => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
                            onLayout={(): any => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
                          />
                        </View>
                      </View>);
                    })
                  }
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          </Carousel>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

The problem I don't understand is that the renderLogItem function to call the LogItem component is never called while the ItemListByDate array is displayed in the logs. No messages are displayed, I just have the grey background of the ScrollView component.

On the other hand, if I use the test array instead of `this.state.messages` with the map function, the message is displayed correctly in the interface and renderLogItem is called correctly.

I understand that when my component is called for the first time, the state is empty and the switch to the componentDidMount function will in my case trigger the update of the state and cause a re-render. This also causes the map function to call up and normally displays each message

Maybe it is due to a display problem, where the messages would be hidden because the initial state of the messages is empty ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that it has to do with the fact that `this.IfeelMessagesBusiness.getAllIfeelMessages()` is asynchronous. So the first time the render method is called, it tries to map òver undefined and it never updates.

Could you try doing a `flatlist` of `Flatlist` maybe ?